# C++ Put wav file into dll

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, audio

I want to include one wav file into dll and play it later.
How to do it? I know how to play file that is in the same direcory. But I want to include around 50 wav files into my dll.

Comment: regardless what way of doing this you choose i strongly discourage including 50 wav files in your dll (because of the size) :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You embed such files as resources.

You need a resource file, and e.g.

```
MY_WAV WAVE "file.wav"
```

Then to play it directly, use PlaySound.

```
PlaySound("MY_WAV", hInstance, SND_RESOURCE);
```

hInstance should be the handle passed to your DllMain

Comment: Close, but needs work.  The resource declaration must use WAVE, not RCDATA.  The first argument should likely be MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_WAV).

Comment: Corrected RCDATA to WAVE. String identifiers work fine, MAKEINTRESOURCE isn't needed ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms903664.aspx

Comment: I'd say [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743679.aspx) is a better resource. Yours is specific to Windows CE. The behavior doesn't appear to differ for this particular function, but that's not always guaranteed. Anyway, +1 for accuracy, though I'd also suggest specifying the `SND_ASYNC` flag.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend using Bass http://www.un4seen.com/ and mp3 instead of wav

if you want to include it in your dll (load the bass.dll from memory) i can tell you how to do that (just not here)

to include wav/mp3 files in your PE (be it exe/dll) use resources